How to get group by transformation in Grafana dashboard table over joined metrics working correctly?
In a relational database you can use the group by feature to eliminate duplicate rows. Here's an example using postgresql:
# select * from test order by cluster;
 cluster | foo | bar  
---------+-----+------
 berta   | 712 |    0
 berta   | 712 | 1223
 hanna   | 838 |  119
 hanna   | 838 |  119
 hanna   | 838 |  119
 hanna   |   3 |  119

select * from test group by(cluster,foo,bar) order by cluster;                                                                                                                               
 cluster | foo | bar  
---------+-----+------
 berta   | 712 | 1223
 berta   | 712 |    0
 hanna   | 838 |  119
 hanna   |   3 |  119

Here, the cluster "hanna" has 3 duplicate rows and 1 other row, and the group by only shows two rows, one of the 3 duplicates and the other one.
I expected the group-by transformation in Grafana to work the same way. But it doesn't.
Problem:
I have two metrics, say (any other combination of metric leads to the same result, so the metric itself doesn't matter, I'd assume):
label_replace(
     kube_pod_container_info{container="elasticsearch", image=~".*elastic.*"},
     "elasticversion",
     "$1",
     "image",
     ".*:(.*)"
)

label_replace(
     kube_pod_container_info{container="kibana", image=~".*kibana.*"},
     "kibanaversion",
     "$1",
     "image",
     ".*:(.*)"
)

I made a dashboard with a table view which shows cluster, elasticversion and kibanaversion. The two metrics are combined using a join transformation on the cluster label and there is a group-by transformation using cluster,elasticversion,kibanaversion. With group-by enabled ALL rows but one are eliminated.
Here's an example:

In the upper two tables I put only one metric into the table view. As can be seen, there are two different versions of the software running on the selected cluster.
However, the bottom table contains a joined table of both metrics and the group-by there just shows ONE row, even if there are two distinct combinations.
Here are the settings of the combined table:
Metrics:

Transforms:

So, how can I make it so, that all unique rows of all combined metrics show up in the table?
Edited to add: this misbehavior ONLY shows when using the group-by transformation over multiple joined metrics. As long as I use 1 metric, group-by works as expected. So, if anyone knows how to generate different version labels based on container name, that would help as well, I think.

To me @Tom, this sounds like something either the distinct or unique function can solve.

Nope, I am using promql in my queries, there are no such functions. Also, I'd need this across two metrics, not just one.

Hmm not quite sure then, if I can think of something I will leave a comment.
